# In karate testing framework, $ does not print the json response

Tags: karate

Using https://github.com/intuit/karate, with the simple script below, the response variable prints on the console, but the $ shortcut does not.

Script

```
  Given url 'http://reqres.in/api/users/2'
  When method GET
  Then status 200   
  * print "Hello, world!"
  * print response
  * print $
```

Output

```
[ForkJoinPool-10-worker-3] 16:33:36.642 [print] Hello, world!
[ForkJoinPool-10-worker-3] 16:33:36.643 [print] {
  "ad": {
    "company": "StatusCode Weekly",
    "text": "A weekly newsletter focusing on software development, infrastructure, the server, performance, and the stack end of things.",
    "url": "http://statuscode.org/"
  },
  "data": {
    "last_name": "Weaver",
    "id": 2,
    "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/josephstein/128.jpg",
    "first_name": "Janet",
    "email": "janet.weaver@reqres.in"
  }
}
[ForkJoinPool-10-worker-3] 16:33:36.644 [print]
```

Per https://github.com/intuit/karate#response, I would expect the $ to be a reference to the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print has to be "pure JS", the `$` is a convenience only for JsonPath expressions: https://github.com/intuit/karate#jsonpath-short-cuts